# writing a USB sniffing kernel module

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, kernel-modules, traffic, fingerprint

Here is my problem :

I have a Raspberry pi zero with Raspbian Jessie and I set up the `dwc2` module to use USB OTG.

I would like **to sniff the USB traffic** from the Raspberry to implement [host identification by USB fingerprinting](http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~butler/pubs/sadfe11.pdf).

BUT **it's not possible to trace USB traffic when the controller is in device (or peripheral) mode**. It's only possible when the controller is configured as a host. So I can't use `usbmon` because no trace is generated.

What I'm trying to do is above my current knowledge. This is why I need some help.

I would like to create a specific module designed for sniffing the USB traffic. But I don't even know where to begin. Do you have some advice ?

Or do you think I should just try to modify the `dwc2` module, find where the request are sent and received ? So I can use printk() or write everything in a file. But it's dirty and I don't really like that.

Thank you for your time !

Edit : I need to sniff USB traffic before any connection is made, mainly because the Rpi is later configured having the knowledge of the host.